# Create Subdomain for websites and email programatically using React and Node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, email, web, nodemailer

On signup, I want to create subdomains and email for each user using React and Node JS.
How can I do that?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24719669/5990249

Answer (score 0):

To make subdomains, you have to look at your Proxy, you can for example make a reverse proxy with Nginx or Caddy, either to redirect.

Imagine that your site is accessible in `http://localhost:8080` and that site.com is a reverse proxy to `http://localhost:8080`.

The following possibilities are available to you:

- `subdomain.site.com` to `http://localhost:8080/subfolder`
- `subdomain.site.com` to `http://localhost:7575`

To send mails with NodeJs, you have to look at Nodemailer (or something else), you will probably need (not obligatory) your own mail server.

Comment: How can you blend React JS with Nginx? We can send an email from Nodemailer if the email is authorized. How can we make emails subdomain in Nodemailer?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "emails subdomain" ?

Comment: I mean like example@mywebsite.com, example2@mywebsite.com, <sub_name>@mywebsite.com.....

Comment: Ah all right! For that you need a mail server. In fact, these are not subdomains but email addresses.